# Django concatenating the result of __unicode__ and string literal

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'legal_entities'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_short
```

The view

```
def my_view(response):
   my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id = ...)
   response = u'АБВГД + my_model #TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need         
                                 #string or buffer, LegalEntityOwn found
```

Just broke my head trying various options. Any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call unicode() function in order to convert your object, in this case my_model in a unicode string.

```
def my_view(response):
   my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id = ...)
   response = u'АБВГД '+ unicode(my_model)
```

Or you could use a cleaner way:

```
def my_view(response):
   my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id = ...)
   response = u'АБВГД %s' % my_model
```

Answer (score 0):

The `my_model` variable is an instance of the model `MyModel`, you should do:

```
response = u'АБВГД ' + my_model.short_name
```

The result of `__unicode__` method is a representation of your model instance that you can see in your admin.